# shell_exec launch firefox from remote client

Tags: php, firefox, shell-exec

Trying to launch a Firefox window in Centos/RHEL5 with Gnome via a PHP. I want the ability to take screenshots of the requested page.

Gave my WWW user sudo rights and confirmed this is working on the server, firefox window opens successfully if the php script is run on the server (as WWW user, hence the whoami echo to confirm user I am running as), however if the PHP page is called from a remote user the firefox window does not open, however the whoami returns the WWW username.

```
<?php

$page= 'index.html';
$launch= "sudo /usr/bin/firefox \"http://another.server.com/".$page."\"";

echo shell_exec('whoami');
echo shell_exec($launch);
?>
```

The WWW user login shell is /bin/bash and no pass required. Running on a private network, not concerned about the sudo access to the WWW user

Comment: You need to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable so that firefix can find the X server.

Comment: Still the same result with the DISPLAY variable for firefox `$launch= "sudo /usr/bin/firefox \"http://another.server.com/".$page."\" --display=:0";`

Comment: I have tried an alternate `$launch= "/usr/bin/firefox -remote \"openURL(http://another.server.com/".$page.")\"";` and receive the error message
`Xlib: connection to ":0.0" refused by server
Xlib: No protocol specified
Error: Failed to connect to X server.`